# How many core i should give for each VM process

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-machines

I have the following on my development environment :-

**Host Machine:-**

1.Windows 7 professional.

2.Core i7 (8 processes).

3.VM workstation.

4.32 GB RAM.

5.700 GB hard disk.

**On the VM:-**

1.Windows server 2008 r2.

2.SQL server 2008 r2.

3.SharePoint server 2013.

4.Visual studio 2012.

5.Team foundation server 2012.

6.4 processes.

7.24 GB RAM

8.80 GB Hard disk.

but there is an option on the VM to define the number of cores for each process , i left it as 1, but not sure how much the number should be in my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. You have 4 processors, or 2 processors and 2 cores - either way you end up with 4 vCPUs. So why do they have this option? Basically to allow you to present whatever underlying hardware you want so you can work around licensing restrictions inside VM guests. [Seriously](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1010184).

Everything vCPU is measured in Mhz/Ghz these days. Back in the olden days you had strict co-scheduling and you had to be very careful about how you allocated your vCPUs. These days though? Go nuts.

It's worth nothing however that your Core i7 doesn't really have 8 cores. It has 4 cores and [hyperthreading](https://superuser.com/questions/122536/what-is-hyper-threading-and-how-does-it-work). Hyperthreading is a way of abstracting the task switching process away from the OS and onto the CPU. It's not a subtitute for having additional cores.

So I'd probably allocate 3 processors (1 core) to your VM and leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean how many processor threads (logical cores) you want to assign to a specific virtual machine? And by processes at point 6 you mean total available physical cores inside VmWare?

If so, so ramp up the cores/threads for the virtual machine with most intensive workload , however I'd not go beyond 2 cores / 4 threads so that the other machines have at least 2 physical processor cores free and workload can be distributed between them by you host machine's hyperthreading and VmWare's workload balancing.